# Coffeescript classes, method and instance variables

Tags: class, variables, coffeescript

I'm going to implement some kind of a Pagniator class in Coffeescript. The Paginator class should hold the information about currentPage, maxPages, columnNames, ...

So my first approach is this:

```
class Paginator
  currentPage = -1
  rowCount = -1
  pageSize= -1
  columnNames = null
  constructor: (@config) ->

  setup: ->
    @config.ajax(
        cache: false
        type: "GET"
        contentType: "application/json"
        dataType: "json"
        success: (data) =>
          this.configurationReceived(data)

    )

  configurationReceived: (data) =>
     this.storeConfig(data)
     this.setupGUI()
     this.loadPage(1)
     $('.pagination ul li').click( ->
         Paginator.loadPage($(this).text())
         return false
      )

  storeConfig: (jsonData) =>
    rowCount = jsonData['rowAmount']
    pageSize = jsonData['pageSize']
    columns = jsonData['columns']
    return
```

The @config is a jsRoutes.controllers.xxx from Play 2.0 Framework jsroutes object. 
On Page load I do

```
paginator = new Paginator jsRoutes.controllers.PlayerController.paginatorConfiguration()
paginator.setup()
```

But I get a "this.storeConfig is not a function" all the time. Can someone help me on that? Do I misuse the class syntax here? My aim is to have the state of the Paginator encapsulated in a Paginator object (instance). On startup I want to do some initialization stuff that is done via a AJAX call to a "route" which is a HTTP endpoint.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the indentation here:

```
$('.pagination ul li').click( ->
    Paginator.loadPage($(this).text())
    return false
 )   # <---
```

should be

```
$('.pagination ul li').click( ->
    Paginator.loadPage($(this).text())
    return false
)
```

Because of this, the following code containing the definition of the method "storeConfig" is not part of the class, therefore "this.storeConfig" is not a function.

You can easily see this if you copy-past your code into the "Try-coffescript" form at coffeescript.org and examine the JavaScript output.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue